# Getting insufficient privilege error while creating users in oracle. How to solve it

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a user for my database

Data:

```
CREATE USER Clerk IDENTIFIED BY MyPassword;
```

Error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

but it appears that I keep getting this error

Comment: Could it be possible you're not having the right permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `CREATE USER` privileges, then you will have to contact your DBA to have the user created. You cannot get around this on your own.